# Nested navigation in eleventy

Tags: eleventy

My data is creating a number of paginated posts. My front matter is as follows:

```
---
pagination:
    data: cms
    size: 1
    alias: article
    addAllPagesToCollections: true
layout: "_base.njk"
tags: articles
permalink: "/articles/{{ article.title | slug }}/"
eleventyComputed:
    title: "{{ article.title }}" 
    eleventyNavigation:
        key: "{{ article.title}}"
        parent: "{{articles}}" //<-- how do I set the parent?
---
```

I would like my nav HTML structure to read

```
<ul>
  <li>articles</li>
    <ul>
     <li>post-1</li>
     <li>post-2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused, if you are saying that these pages are tagged with 'articles', can't parent just have a hard coded value:   parent: articles.  ?

Comment: Thank you. I did hardcode in the end. Initially, I was trying to do everything programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create hierarchy by using **macro**'s.

But there's an **another way**: flatten that hierarchy and assign to each node a variable that describes the nesting level.

Then a similar code (as below) can be used to render that hierarchy:

```
{% set level = 0 %}

{% for category in collections.categoryCollection %}

    {% set ulCount = (category.level - level) | abs %}

    {% for i in range(0, ulCount) %}
        {% if category.level > level %}
            <ul>
        {% else  %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}

    <li>
        <a href="{{ category.categoryUri | url | normalize | firstPage(globals.categories.category.postPageSize) }}">
            {{ category.categoryName }} ( {{category.items.length}} / {{ category.allItems.length }} )
        </a>
    </li>

    {% set level = category.level %}

{% endfor %}

{% for i in range(0, level) %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps, I know it works, used them to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: Just ignore some extras I've used like the normalize or firstPage plugin, that's not important for the concept of displaying the hierarchy.